# Swift: How to know which Storyboard is active

Tags: ios, swift, function, storyboard

I am trying to run a function only when a certain storyboard is active.

Example:

```
    if view == secondStoryboard {   //Don't know what to do here
        functionOnSecondStoryboard("Test")
    }
```

This may be a very simple fix, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by active storyboard? If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you can get the storyboard from which a view controller was instantiated using

```
let storyboard = self.storyboard
//now you can compare it to other storyboards
if storyboard == storyBoardNumberOne {
}
```

You can get its name with key-value coding and compare the string names

```
let name = storyboard?.valueForKey("name")
```

But be careful using the KVC to get the name - this isn't a documented feature and I cannot guarantee if an app using it would be accepted in the AppStore.